# Can someone teach me how to get this output

Tags: java

I'm new to java. I'm trying to make my program output this [5,4] [3] [2,1] but instead I get [5,5] [4,4] [3,3] [2,2] [1,1].. what am I missing? I tried to answer it on my own but I just can't think of the answer.

Here's my full code:

```
   public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Array Size:");
    int arrSize = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The Size of your Array is "+ arrSize);
    int arr[] = new int[arrSize];
    System.out.println("Enter "+arrSize+" Elements of your Array: ");
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    for(int i=arr.length-1; i>=0;i--){
        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]+","+arr[i]));
    }

}
```

Comment: yes but how can I make it [5,4]? sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: I tried 5 for the size of array and 1 2 3 4 5 for the elements.

Comment: ok. if i enter 4 what output do you want?

Comment: should be [4,3] [2,1] then if 1 2 3 4 5 output should be [5,4] [3] [2,1] is this possilbe? I'm just trying stuff hehe

Comment: oh my bad. I already edited thanks for reminding me.

Comment: if i enter 7 what output do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Array Size:");
        int f,midd=0;
        int arrSize = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The Size of your Array is "+ arrSize);
        int arr[] = new int[arrSize];
        System.out.println("Enter "+arrSize+" Elements of your Array: ");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        if(arrSize%2==0){
            f=0;
        }
        else {
            f=1;
            midd=(int)(arrSize/2/2)+1;
        }
        for(int i=arrSize-1; i>=0;){
            if(f==0)
            {
                System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]+","+arr[i-1]));
                i-=2;
            }
            else{
                if(midd==i){
                    System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]));
                    i--;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]+","+arr[i-1]));
                    i-=2;
                }
            }
        }
```

provide this program inside main method
Output:

```
Enter Array Size:5
The Size of your Array is 5
Enter 5 Elements of your Array: 
1
2
3
4
5
[5,4][3][2,1]
```

.

```
Enter Array Size:4
The Size of your Array is 4
Enter 4 Elements of your Array: 
1
2
3
4
[4,3][2,1]
```

.

```
Enter Array Size:7
The Size of your Array is 7
Enter 7 Elements of your Array: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
[7,6][5,4][3][2,1]
```

Comment: this one works thanks a lot! I'm gonna study it.

Comment: Remember to upvote and accept answers that work

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try the following. I think what you need is to split the array as a pair.

I am assuming you will have middle pair with one element in case of odd length and all pairs will have two elements in case of even length of the array.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Array Size:");
    int arrSize = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The Size of your Array is "+ arrSize);
    int arr[] = new int[arrSize];
    System.out.println("Enter "+arrSize+" Elements of your Array: ");
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    int i=arr.length-1;
    for(; i>arr.length/2;i-=2){
        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]+","+arr[i-1]));
    }
    if(arr.length %2 == 0){
        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]+","+arr[i-1]));
        i-=2;
    }else{
        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]));
        i-=1;
    }
    for(; i>0;i-=2){
        System.out.print(Arrays.asList(arr[i]+","+arr[i-1]));
    }

}
```

Comment: this code works. thanks a lot! I'm gonna study it. thanks guys

Comment: Remember to upvote and accept answers that work!